# How to get triggering_element

Tags: forms, 8

I want to get `triggering_element` element on `form_alter` after form rebuild, Also I know that this could be used on submit handler on Ajax controller to findout which element cause form submit or Ajax triggered.

**So how can I get triggering_element after Ajax call or form submissions?**

Comment: There's a method to get it in the form state object (probably getTriggeringElement).

Comment: yes,after a look on FormState.php I findout how to get it, some question maybe could help  Drupalists at future, if you google "How to get Trigggerdelement on drupal 8 " you didn't find simple solution,

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Eyal is correct. FormState has a method [getTriggeringElement](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Form%21FormStateInterface.php/function/FormStateInterface%3A%3AgetTriggeringElement/8.2.x). See the [original change record](https://www.drupal.org/node/2310411) for details.

```
$form_state->getTriggeringElement();
```

and if you want to get id try

```
$triggerdElement = $form_state->getTriggeringElement();
$htmlIdofTriggeredElement = $triggerdElement['#id'];
```

Comment: Submit buttons often return 'op' and you can't tell which button it is. Then you have to get the id from the parent: `$clicked_button = end($form_state->getTriggeringElement()['#parents']);`

Answer (score 5):

My preferred method is:

```
$triggering_element = $form_state->getTriggeringElement();
$button_name = $triggering_element['#name'];
if ($button_name === 'button1') {
  // ...
}
```

Works both for validateForm() and submitForm().

Ensure you have #name for all your buttons.
E.g.:

```
$form['button1'] = [
  '#type' => 'submit',
  '#name' => 'button1',
  '#value' => $this->t('Button 1'),
];
```

Compared to $triggering_element['#id'] it's more stable because #id auto-generated and can change implicitly.

Compared to $triggering_element['#value'] it's better because:
- #value can be not unique;
- #value is a part UI (button label) and frequently changes.

Comment: This is definitely a better method.
You should always set a unique '#name' for your button. If you don't, and you use the same '#value' for more than one button, only the last button with that '#value' will have it's array returned in $form_state['triggering_element']

Answer (score 1):

## 3

```
$triggering_element = $form_state->getTriggeringElement();
$button_name = $triggering_element['#name'];
if ($button_name === 'button1') {
  // ...
}
```

Works both for validateForm() and submitForm().

Ensure you have #name for all your buttons. E.g.:

```
$form['button1'] = [
  '#type' => 'submit',
  '#name' => 'button1',
  '#value' => $this->t('Button 1'),
];
```

This is the correct answer.